# Operator+ Overloading Problems

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

For my CS class, our teacher wants us to create our own string class. I'm just in the beginning stages and am currently trying to overload `operator+`. He wants it as a non-member function. Here is what I have so far:

This is the `String` header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

#ifndef STRING_HPP
#define STRING_HPP



class String
{
private:
    int len;
    char* str;
public:
    String();               // default constructor
    String(String const& s);    // copy constructor
    String(char const* s);      // C-string constructor
    ~String() {delete str;};                // destructor
    char* const getString();    //get string for printing
    String& operator=(char const* c);
    String& operator=(String const& s);

};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, String s)
{
    return os << s.getString();
}

String operator+(String const& lhs, String const& rhs) {
    len = lhs.len + rhs.len;
    str = new char[len];
    std::strcat(str,lhs);
    std::strcat(str,rhs);
}

#endif
```

This is the `String.cpp` file:

```
#include "string.hpp"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

String::String()
{
    len = 0;
    str = new char[len];
}

String::String(String const& s) // copy constructor
{
    len = s.len;
    str = new char[len]; 
    std::strcpy(str,s.str);

}
String::String(char const* s)   // C-string constructor
{
    len = std::strlen(s);
    str = new char[len];
    std::strcpy(str,s);

}

char* const String::getString()
{
    return str;
}

String& String::operator=(char const* c)
{
    // 1: allocate new memory and copy the elements
    int newLen = std::strlen(c);
    char* newStr = new char[newLen]; 
    std::strcpy(newStr,c);

    // 2: deallocate old memory
    delete [] str;

    // 3: assign the new memory to the object
    str = newStr;
    len = newLen;
}

String& String::operator=(String const& s)
{
    // 1: allocate new memory and copy the elements
    int newLen = s.len;
    char* newStr = new char[newLen]; 
    std::strcpy(newStr,s.str);

    // 2: deallocate old memory
    delete [] str;

    // 3: assign the new memory to the object
    str = newStr;
    len = newLen;
 }
```

and here is the implementation of `main`:

```
#include "string.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    String s1;
    String s2 = "test";
    String s3 = s2;

    std::cout << s1 << '\n';
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
    std::cout << s3 << '\n';

    String a = "one";
    String b = "two";

    a = b;
    b = "three";

    std::cout << a << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';

    String hello = "hello ";
    String world = "world";
    String concat = hello + world;

    std::cout << concat << '\n';
}
```

Everything works until that last `concat`. I cannot change `Main.cpp` because it is provided by the professor.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get `operator+` to work?

Comment: Your `operator+` function should fail to compile...   Also it contains a logic error, you call `strcat` on a pointer to uninitialized storage.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the actual and the desired behavior.

Comment: Another thing is that you continually dont' allocate enough memory, you are forgetting about null terminators

Comment: I think you have the const in your `getString` in the wrong place? Is it necessary for `operator <<` to copy your string? I'm not sure how you handle an empty string as per your default constructor is a good way.

Comment: @M.M it did fail compile. Thanks for the reminder about the null terminators, I also fixed the strcat issue I believe. However, it still fails to compile. It can't seem to access the member variables str and int...

Comment: @NeilKirk That function was provided to me by the teacher...

Comment: @LeonhartDan member variables can only be used when you have an object which they are a member of...   so when you're in a non-member function you have to say which object (e.g. `foo.str`, not just `str`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
str = new char[len];
```

in all the functions.  That does not have enough memory to hold the terminating null character. You need to use:

```
str = new char[len+1];
```

In the `operaor+` function, using `strcat` just after memory allocation is cause for undefined behavior since `str` is not initialized.

You need to use:

```
str = new char[len+1];
str[0] = '\0';
std::strcat(str,lhs);
std::strcat(str,rhs);
```

or

```
str = new char[len+1];
std::strpy(str,lhs);    // strcpy, not strcat
std::strcat(str,rhs);
```

**Update**

The complete implementation of `operator+()`:

```
String operator+(String const& lhs, String const& rhs) {
    int len = lhs.len + rhs.len;
    char* str = new char[len+1];
    std::strcpy(str,lhs);
    std::strcat(str,rhs);
    String ret(str);
    delete [] str;
    return ret;
}
```

You can simplify the function if you implement `String::operator+=(String const& rhs)`. Then, you can use:

```
String operator+(String const& lhs, String const& rhs) {
    String ret(lhs);
    ret += rhs;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. However, the program still fails to compile. "str" and "len" are not working because they aren't declared in the scope. operator+ is not able to access the private members. how do I fix that?

Comment: @LeonhartDan Make `operator+` a `friend`

Comment: @NeilKirk That's what I was thinking as well, and I tried that, but it failed. I'm starting to wonder if I don't understand what a non-member operator is and how it works...

Comment: @LeonhartDan, use a simpler class/struct to experiment with that. Something like `struct Foo {int a; int b;};`

Comment: @LeonhartDan In the class `friend String operator+(String const& lhs, String const& rhs)` then define the function outside the class.

Comment: @NeilKirk If I follow correctly, this is what I have. And it still doesn't work..
In class: `friend String operator+(String const& lhs, String const& rhs);`. Then after the class, I declare the operator+ as such:
    `String operator+(String const& lhs, String const& rhs) {
     len = lhs.len + rhs.len;
     str = new char[len];
     std::strcpy(str,lhs);
     std::strcat(str,rhs);
    }`

Comment: Where is `len` declared? It cannot come from nowhere!

Comment: @RSahu That would be it, Thanks. The idea of creating and returning a string wasn't clicking with me. I also made the mistake of implementing the  operator+ in the .hpp file not main.cpp. Thanks so much for your help!